# Can I call one thread sampler from another thread in Jmeter WebDriver Sampler?

Tags: jmeter, webdriver

I have just started using Jmeter WebDriver Sampler for automating performance of an application. I'm curious to know that can i call one webdriver sampler from another sampler?.Is it possible in Jmeter. Because I need to login and logout in every sampler.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it is possible via [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) and [JSR223 bridge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html) however it will be too complicated and in general [you ain't gonna need it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

There are 2 main points which you might not know:

1. JMeter executes Samplers **upside down** so if you have the following structure:

   - Login Sampler
   - Logout Sampler

     Jmeter first will execute Login than Logout. Browser instance will be shared across the samplers
2. There is a mechanism in JMeter which helps avoiding code duplication so if you have Logout sampler(s) somewhere in your test plan and would like to re-use it in several places instead of copying and pasting it each time you can call it using [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller)